# Sony xperia M (C1904) not detected on Windows 8 and ADT

Tags: android, driver, adb, adt, sony

I'm not able to debug android application on Sony XPeria M(C1904).
It's not detecting on Windows 8 and ADT.

Anyone, any solution?

Comment: Are you getting something like `?????????`

Comment: Where did you find an update for PC companion? I'm running W8 pro 64 and http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/pc-companion/ which seems to be the latest. What the heck is wrong with this device, I've already spent many hours trying to connect it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have configured the device correctly,
please follow the below link 
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: Kapil... Thanks for the reply... Turned out that there was no update patch released for Windows 8. I've updated PC Companion yesterday and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to Go Settings>about Phone>Build Number and tap it seven time.Press back and you will see "Developers Options "now and check the "Enable Debugging".Install latest google drivers, if this doesnt work try the following soution 
Try to usePDa Net [here](http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=PdaNet&platform=Windows%2CMac%2CiOS%2CAndroid%2CWebware%2CMobile&searchtype=downloads"PDA")! Install it on your PC ,Connect your phone it will detect the missing driver from automatically